# Infinite loop while iterating dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Say i have two dict like this,

```
data_dict = {'A1': 5, 'A2': 10, 'A3': 15}
```

and

```
formula_dict = {'A4': 'A1*A3', 'A6': 'A1+A5+A2', 'A5': 'A1+A2+A3+A4'}
```

I am iterating thro' the formula dict and evaluating the expression as it gets and then again appending back to copy of `data_dict` until all the formula are evaluated completely. The logic works fine but it causes infinite loop. How to resolve this infinite loop?

```
def update_some(convert_dict, in_dict):
    in_dict_update = in_dict.copy()
    convert_dict_update = convert_dict.copy()
    while convert_dict_update:
        for k, v in list(convert_dict_update.items()):
            print(convert_dict_update.items())
            try:
                return_value = eval(v, in_dict)
                in_dict_update[k] = return_value
                convert_dict_update.pop(k)
            except NameError:
                continue

            update_some(convert_dict_update, in_dict_update)
        print(in_dict_update)
    print('After ', convert_dict_update)
    print(in_dict_update)
    return in_dict_update


# update_some(converted_dict, data_dict)
```

Also printing the `in_dict_update` prints some garbage key, value pairs like some `__builtins__`

Comment: @Hacketo, why? `len(convert_dict_update)` is false (equal to `0`) if and only if `convert_dict_update` is false (is an empty `dict`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `eval` uses `in_dict` as a global dict that lacks standard global attributes. So python adds them for you. Try:

```
return_value = eval(v, None, in_dict)
```

However, you should try to reduce the complexity of your recursion. I’d suggest:

```
def update_some(convert_dict, in_dict):
    in_dict_update = in_dict.copy()
    skipped_values = {}
    for k,v in convert_dict.items():
        try:
            return_value = eval(v, None, in_dict_update)
        except NameError:
            skipped_values[k] = v
        else:
            in_dict_update[k] = return_value
    if skipped_values:
        in_dict_update = update_some(skipped_values, in_dict_update)
    return in_dict_update
```